# Is there a framework for tracking & notifying consumers about background tasks in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, background-process

I have a background task in an ASP.NET application that updates a database when a user logs in. A page on the site (that the user may or may not visit) uses that data to display some charts, etc. I'm hoping someone could recommend a framework/example that would facilitate tracking background tasks so that I can:

1. Prevent a duplicate update task from starting if the same user logs out/in
2. Know when to render a subset of the page if the data isn't yet available
3. Update the page if the user is viewing it when the update process is completed
4. Preferably support the same tracking/notification for tasks that aren't user specific

I know at some point something like SignalR will be necessary to to the 'update when the process is completed' bit, but I think the more challenging bit would be the thread-safe activity tracking & notification system on the server side.

Can you recommend a good framework for doing this efficiently?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't want to be doing these kinds of tasks using web server threads. The web server should be tasked with handling HTTP requests and generating HTTP responses as quickly as possible. To that end, look into using a messaging architecture like MSMQ, NServiceBus or even Azure queues or Azure service bus to offload long-running or resource-intensive work.

Comment: I agree with the above and suggest looking at windows workflow hosted in iis.

Comment: Absolutely, but what about short-running, non-intensive work like a two second database update that the user needn't wait for to complete? There is probably a class of operations that could be done asynchronously, but not necessitate adding the infrastructure (maintenance, configuration) of a message bus, its dependent message queue system, and an entirely new service to perform the task. I don't know much about node.js but I'm thinking someone building an app in an async-by-default environment would have lots of those cases.

Comment: In that case, consider using fire-and-forget syntax with the asynchronous support in C# 5.0.